# Cannot find windowdefender to modify my Windows Firewall settings

Tags: windows-10, firewall

Here is the networking settings page in my **Win 10 Pro**

[image]

When I click on 'Windows Firewall' I got:

[image]

But if I click the button to the MS store, I got this:

[image]

There is no such app in the store.

What can I do now?

Comment: Run `wf.msc` which will open old Windows Firewall Control Panel.

Comment: It works. If you turn your comment into an answer I will accept it

Comment: What you are describing is weird. Your Windows might be corrupted or infected. Run [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html) and antivirus scans.

Comment: For reference https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1KPT.png is what you should be seeing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Firewall settings can also be modified through Advanced Firewall options from Management Console Panel. Start it with this command `mmc.exe wf.msc` or run `wf.msc`. This is the same MMC snapin like in Windows 7.